# I want to change the word of the sentence using Python

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
text = "i eat salad"
```

I would like to change `eat` to `ate` to get:

```
text = "i ate salad"
```

Do i have to use join or split?

```
text.split()[1] = 'ate'
print(text)
```

I've tried this before unsuccessfully.

Comment: you mean `l = text.split(); l[1] = 'ate'` then `print(" ".join(l))`

Comment: Alternatively [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) if you're looking to blanket match all occurrences.

Comment: if OP needs word boundary that's not going to cut it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've edited my comment to give a brief note, but yes that is true.

Comment: If you *have* to use split and join, I suggest `text.replace('eat', 'ate') + ''.join(''.split())` ;)

Comment: @hyunjinchoi If you're trying to modify a specific 'i-th' word type of deal, you should mention this in your question.

Comment: If word boundaries are an issue, `re.replace` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

just split and *store* the result.

Then change the second word, and join again:

```
text = "i eat salad"
words = text.split()
words[1] = 'ate'
print(" ".join(words))
```

Comment: note: I obviously don't care about rep since this is CW. Can someone explain the downvote? I checked for proper duplicates but could not find a proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace() to change it.

```
text = "i eat salad"
text = text.replace('eat', 'ate')
print(text)
```